# Applicability of the Ito's lemma

Tags: itos-lemma, geometric-brownian

`Ito's lemma` is used to find the `stochastic process` of the function of a `Geometric Brownian process`.

My question, is there any limitation of the kind of function that can be considered for correctly using the `Ito's lemma`, apart from just being continuous everywhere within the domain of the function?

Any insight will be highly helpful

Comment: The answer there is much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It also needs to be twice differentiable.